# Xamarin.Android always getting previously selected Language and not current

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android

I am developing an app in Xamarin.Android and I am fetching the current system language using

```
CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture.TwoLetterISOLanguageName;
```

It returns the current system language but when I close the app and go to settings and change the language to some another and again open the app then it still returns the old language only. When I re install the app it then shows me the new language.

Comment: I created a simple xamarin.android project and tried to get CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture.TwoLetterISOLanguageName; And I found that, when I start the app, then go to the settings app to change the language, then open the app again, it returns the old language. But if I make the app stop by slide it out of the task stack, then open the app again, it returns the new language. So the problem is that when you "close" the app, you don't really close it, you just make it unvisible, the Activity is just paused not stopped.

Comment: tried that as well doesn't work, only when I reinstall the app it recognizes.

Comment: Where do you write CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture.TwoLetterISOLanguageName;? I put the line in the OnResume() method. And I tried it in the OnCreate method, too, it also works well. I would post my code in the answer and hopes it will help.

Comment: I wrote that inside `OnCreate()` after `SetContentView()` and it's not working there.

Comment: I also tried writing inside OnCreate() after SetContentView() , it workes all right. Then it may have something to do with other code. Would you please share your full code so that I can reproduce the issue and then try to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

I created a simple xamarin.android project and as I explained in the comment, I put the CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture.TwoLetterISOLanguageName; in the OnResume() method.Then I start the app, go to the settings app to change the language, then open the app again, it returns the old language. But if I make the app stop by slide it out of the task stack, then open the app again, it returns the new language. 
The code is like this:

```
public class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity
    {
        TextView tv;
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
            // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.activity_main);
        }

        protected override void OnResume()
        {
            base.OnResume();

            var lang = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.TwoLetterISOLanguageName;
            Log.Debug("OnResume", lang);

            tv = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.textView1);
            tv.Text = lang;
        }
    }
```